# plot area graph using javascriptRRD library

Tags: javascript, rrdtool, rrd

I am using javascriptRRD library ( http://javascriptrrd.sourceforge.net/ ) to read a rrd file and draw the graph from it. I am using javascriptrrd.wlibs.js file that is available in [download section](http://javascriptrrd.sourceforge.net/download.html).

I am using below code to call the library file  :

```
   flot_obj=new rrdFlotAsync(graphDiv.id); // graphDiv.id is the id of graph container
   flot_obj.reload(url) // source url of RRD file.
```

the above lines of code draw a line graph but I need to draw area graph . 
  If anyone has tried this before , please let me know what changes to be made in rrd library file.

> Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the library file  javascriptrrd.wlibs.js , there is a graph_options , global variable , in that fill:true needs to be added.